# Generate signal with sinusoidal change of frequency

Tags: signal

What is the mathematical formula to generate a sine wave, which changes its period sinusoidally?
E.g. a sinusoidal signal, with sinusoidal change of frequency.

Comment: It might be better to ask this on the Math.SE site. They have MathJax over there that will make it easier to write mathematics.

Comment: Basically, you're looking for y=sin([sin(ax)+e]x). You have to play with the constants a lot to make it work the way you want.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about a mathematical formula which is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm presuming you mean something like this (the blue waveform): -

[image]

The red waveform is amplitude modulation and the blue waveform is frequency modulation.

This should be the formula you need: -

[image]

- y(t) is the FM output
- fc is the unmodulated carrier frequency
- f(delta)/fm is the modulation index - see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation) wiki article
- fm is the modulating frequency
- t is time